How to change cursor theme?
How can one change the mouse cursor used in Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm? (Wayfire)
I have tried a number of things: setting a cursor theme through lxappearance, manually editing configs for GTKs 2 and 3, using update-alternatives to select a different cursor theme, setting cursor_theme in wayfire.cfg;  but it seems like RPiOS just ignores everything I do.
(This question is not to be confused with this XFCE-specific question -- I would like to be able to change the cursor theme without installing things from another DE.  This should be possible in base RPiOS.)

I cannot definitively answer your question about themes, but AFAIK it is NOT possible.
The things you referenced are there because they are inherited from Debian but the underlying tools and themes are not supported (as attempting to install them would show).
Simon Long who develops the Raspberry Pi OS Desktop has posted on the News about the changes. See https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/
Only limited software has been adapted - indeed this was also the case for Bullseye which removed the tools which enabled limited customisation of the window appearance.

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme shows
'Adwaita' (PixFlat is based on Adwaita) but any attempt to change fails with error.
(lxappearance:92163): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:54:36.808: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
Even though apt shows adwaita-icon-theme/stable,stable,now 43-1 all [installed,automatic]
I have had some limited success changing appearance e.g. I prefer macOS buttons on the left and can get something like that with
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
